# Права доступа на php файл с паролем БД

Tags: php, mysql

Храню логин и пароль к базе в файле connection.php, он лежит на уровень выше корневой директории сайта.
1. Какие права доступа нужно установить на файл connection.php чтобы обеспечить безопасность хранимых в нем данных?
2. Нужно ли как-то защищать этот файл от поисковых роботов или они не смогут его проиндексировать, т. к. он лежит вне корневой директории?

файл index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../connection.php';

try
{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user, $password);
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
$e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
```

файл connection.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'dbname'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'user'; // имя пользователя
$password = 'mysuperpassword'; // пароль
```

Comment: соединения к бд по уму разрешены только с того хоста где крутится сайт. а значит никто даже узнав пароль от бд не сможет к ней подключиться.

Answer (score 0):

Беспокоится не стоит, так многие фреймворки устроены.
Первое, файл никак не достать поисковым системам, он находится в не читаемом из WEB пространстве сервера.
Второе, даже если такой файл запустить из веб, то на стороне сервера произойдет только присвоение переменным, но не их вывод в браузер (считается что запускаемые php файлы обрабатываются интерпретатором PHP)

Comment: Спасибо, про поисковых роботов понял. Если php крашнется, то при определённых настройках (наверное) apache, содержимое файла появится на экране. Какие минимальные публичные права нужны для файлов, которые подключаются через include? Только чтение, или только выполнение, либо и чтение и выполнение? И если бы файл лежал в корне сайта, то какие права нужно установить чтобы, php мог их исполнять, а через браузер они были бы не видны и скачивать их было бы нельзя. Или такое можно реализовать только через htaccess?

Comment: На счет когда крашнется сам PHP я с таким не сталкивался. Но можешь попробовать, если конфиг файл не исполняемый, а подключаемый, может достаточно будет прав только на чтение владельца. если нет, добавь права на выполнение владельца.